# Who is the King Darius in Haggai 1:1?

Tags: history, hebrew-bible

"In the second year of King Darius, on the first day of the sixth month, the word of the Lord came through the prophet Haggai to Zerubbabel son of Shealtiel, governor of Judah, and to Joshua son of Jozadak, the high priest." (Haggai 1:1)

Did the author of Haggai intend to refer to the same person as the person intended by the author of Daniel in the words "Darius the Mede"?

Comment: Daniel is (perhaps intentionally) confusing two distinct persons. In his fifth and sixth chapters, he describes a king whose deeds mirror those of Cyrus, but whom he ostensibly refers to as Darius. From the beginning of his eleventh chapter, we deduce that this is none other than Darius II. This apparent confusion seems vitally important when interpreting the prophecy contained in his ninth chapter. The edict to rebuild Jerusalem, including the Temple, has indeed been issued in the first year of Cyrus, but 540 BC + 490 years = 50 BC. On the other hand, however, 420 BC + 490 years = 70 AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the prophet Daniel calls him a Mede not Persian, as Darius in Haggai was of Persian descent. Darius the Mede’s reign appeared to be quite brief over Babylon. Cyrus of Persia obtained  absolute kingship around 539 BC and was king over the entire Persian empire (Babylonian incuded). He reigned until his death in 530 BC. His son Cambyses took over from 530-522 BC. In spring of 522 either a usurper or Cambyses brother (one of the 2), becomes king. Then on September 29th 522 BC Darius Hystaspes killed the Magi and assumed kingship. Below is a portion of Darius’s behistun inscription

Behistun inscription

> There was none who dared to act against Gaumâta, the Magian, until I came. Then I prayed to Ahuramazda; Ahuramazda brought me help. On the tenth day of the month Bâgayâdiš (29 September 522 BCE) I, with a few men, slew that Gaumâta, the Magian, and the chief men who were his followers. At the stronghold called Sikayauvatiš, in the district called Nisaia in Media, I slew him; I dispossessed him of the kingdom. By the grace of Ahuramazda I became king; Ahuramazda granted me the kingdom.>

Darius the Mede was out of the picture 18 yearsish before Darius the Persian became king.

Here’s a list of the kings of Persia years of kingship. This does not include Darius the Mede as the Medes were essentially out of the picture and Persians took full control around 539 BC. This covers Persian kings only.

https://www.thoughtco.com/timeline-of-the-ancient-rulers-of-persia-120250

Their dates are a bit off compared with mine but through the inscription the indication is he become king in 522 BC